# Rails 4 - Ransack Form - Format text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

My ransack form has a date to and from search using a datepicker for each.  The search and results works great, however I would like to style the form fields so that when the results load, the datetime can be formated just to_date.  I am unsure how to access the value used in the form.  I could just use the value parameter and apply the styling, but I do not know the variable to use.

```
<%= f.text_field :order_date_lt, class: "", id: "datepicker1", value: ?????.to_date.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that in this case @q.order_date_lt, if it is present, will be able to be formatted that way